# Javascript Can't catch an error inside map function

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, undefined

let's say I have a usersList like this:

```
var usersList = [
            { firstName: 'Adam', lastName: 'Yousif', age: 23 },
            { firstName: 'Mohamed', lastName: 'Ali' },
            { firstName: 'Mona', lastName: 'Ahmed', age: 19 },
        ];
```

Now I want to call the map function on usersList and return a modified list like so :

```
var returnList = usersList.map((_user) => {
            var _age;
            try {
                _age = _user.age;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('I caught error here : ', error); // <-- not printed
                _age = 'FAILSAFE-VAULE'; // <-- not set
            }
            var obj = {
                firstName: _user.firstName,
                lastName: _user.lastName,
                age: _age
            }
            return obj;
        });
```

I have a try-catch block inside the map function, the purpose of it is to replace the undefined property "age" of the second user with a `'FAILSAFE-VALUE'`. but it doesn't work as should.

```
console.log(returnList);
// prints
// [ 
//     { firstName: 'Adam', lastName: 'Yousif', age: 23 },
//     { firstName: 'Mohamed', lastName: 'Ali', age: undefined }, <-- not what I want
//     { firstName: 'Mona', lastName: 'Ahmed', age: 19 } 
// ]
```

How to catch an error inside the javascript map function?

Thank you

Comment: I dont think you should be try and catching in map...

Comment: You're assigning `age = 'FAILSAFE-VAULE';` but never using `age`? Change `age: _user.age` to `age: age`

Comment: You are right @amcquaid . I edited the question. It should make sense now. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to do try catch for that:

```js
usersList.map((_user) => {
            return {
                firstName: _user.firstName,
                lastName: _user.lastName,
                age: _user.age || 'FAILSAFE-VAULE'
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because nothing is thrown (the `age` is just `undefined`). If you want information about this "error" during the `map`-operation, the first part of the snippet may be an idea. If you really want to use `try - catch`, use the second part (it throws 'manually' when `_user.age` is `undefined`). The latter demonstrates (by the way) that `try - catch` *does* work within a `map`-operation.

```js
const usersList = [{
    firstName: 'Adam',
    lastName: 'Yousif',
    age: 23
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Mohamed',
    lastName: 'Ali'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Mona',
    lastName: 'Ahmed',
    age: 19
  },
];

const getFailSafe = user => {
  if (!user.age) {
    console.log(`Note: user.age not available for ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`);
    return `FAILSAFE-VAULE`;
  }
  return user.age;
};

// 1. use a warning if .age not present
const returnList = usersList
  .map((_user) => ({
      firstName: _user.firstName,
      lastName: _user.lastName,
      age: getFailSafe(_user)
    })
);

// 2. throw an Error if .age not present
const returnListWithError = usersList
  .map((_user) => {
    let retVal = {
      firstName: _user.firstName,
      lastName: _user.lastName,
    }
    try {
      retVal.age = _user.age || 
        (() => {
          throw new Error(`ERROR: user.age not available for ${
            _user.firstName} ${_user.lastName} (will continue with 'FAILSAFE-VAULE')`);
          })();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`${err.message}`);
      retVal.age = `FAILSAFE-VAULE`;
    }
    
    return retVal;
  });

console.log(returnList.find(v => isNaN(v.age)));
console.log(returnListWithError.find(v => isNaN(v.age)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`try...catch` block would not work there as after accessing a value which does not exist you just receive an `undefined`

just do it next way:

```
var returnList = usersList.map((_user) => {
    return {
        firstName: _user.firstName,
        lastName: _user.lastName,
        age: _user.age ? _user.age  : 'FAILSAFE-VAULE'
    }
});
```